# Delay during client to server message transfer

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking

I have made a dummy client to server message sending application. Here client is an android device and server is simple Java Server that prints on console the messages it recieves. I have used sockets to implement this. When I run the application there is a delay of 2-3 seconds between sending message from client and printing of that message by the server at the console when the client is android device. However, when the client is another pc, there is no significant delay. How to remove this delay and what are its sources? Someone please help!

My code for server is :

```
import java.net.*;

import java.io.*;

class Server    
{

void connectNread()
{ 
    System.out.println("Server Started!! ... ");
    try
    {
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(5000);
        Socket s = ss.accept();
        System.out.println(s.getInetAddress().getHostName() + "   Connected!!!");
        InputStreamReader stream = new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader reader =  new BufferedReader(stream);
        String message = null;
        message  = reader.readLine();
        long  output = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(output+" : " +  message);
        stream.close();
        s.close();
        ss.close();
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

public static void main(String s[])
{
    new Server().connectNread();
}


}
```

While the code at android client is :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Button connectButton;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    connectButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.connect);
}
private class connectToNetwork extends AsyncTask<Integer,Integer,Integer>
{
    protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... i)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket s = new Socket("192.168.1.22",5000);
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
            writer.println("Its Printed!!");
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            s.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return 1;
    }
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer progress) 
    {
        ///setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Integer  result) 
    {
        //showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
    }

}

public void connect(View v) 
{
    String TAG = null;
    new connectToNetwork().execute(1,1,1);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Please suggest where i am doing wrong.All the devices are on the same wifi network.

Comment: Android device?  PC?  What type of links are involved in the route/s to those devices?  I'm guessing ethernet LAN to PC?  What about the android device?

Comment: Android device is my android phone. PC is my laptop which has the server code running. Both of them are on the same wireless network.Apologize for not stating that in the question.
Am I able to clear myself properly?

Comment: Your client is only sending something and then closes. The client does not read the echo from the server. So you cannot measure a round trip time to begin with.

Comment: @greenapps : Clicking on the Connect button on the client and receiving the echo message at the server has a delay of 2-3 seconds. I am not measuring the round trip time.

Comment: You have no echo server. There is nothing echoed to begin with i have seen now. The server only logs the received message. Please do not speak about an echo server if you don't have one. Quite confusing as you have seen.

Comment: You say that the delay is between sending and receiving. But i think that it is different. Establishing the connection might take the most time. Please investigate what takes time.

Comment: Thanks @greenapps. That resolved my issue. Still not sure why it takes so long to establish my connection, but I can move forward on my app now.